# How do i revoke an ERC20 or ERC721 token approval given to a smart contract

Tags: erc-20-approve

I've granted allowance to a smart contract to spend some tokens on my behalf, but it seems i gave it unlimited access.

I want to revoke this access as i now know that this could be a potential opening for an attack on my address(wallet).

I noticed that block explorers like etherscan or wallets like coinbase have a tool that makes revoking approvals possible.

I'm interested in knowing how this would work, and how i can build something similar.
I dont think this is a feature that ERC20 OR ERC721 tokens currently support natively.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to call the contract's function setApproval(ERC721) or setApprovalForAll(ERC1155 & ERC721) and pass false as the bool value

**EDIT** - added ERC20 standard

```typescript
//for ERC1155 & ERC721
function setApprovalForAll(address operator, bool approved)

//only for ERC721
function approve(address to, uint256 tokenId)

//for ERC20 according to the EIP-20
function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success)
```

Comment: It seems not all tokens support this though. 
This USDC token for example: https://etherscan.io/token/0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48#writeProxyContract

Comment: It does but the function name is different; this one is an ERC20 :D I suggest you take a look at https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20, that is the Standard functions that must be implemented; maybe you can also search for the documentation of the smart contracts you want to interact with